# How to open an image in drawable folder using android imageview applications?

Tags: android, android-intent, imageview

I want to open an image in my drawable folder via default imageview applications of my phone (Gallery, etc.).

My image location: drawable/image.png

Code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(""), "image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

What do I need to write in Uri.parse function to see the image file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do that you have to copy your image in drawable folder to SD card and then give the path of the file in SD card to intent.

Here is the code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.imagename);

        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);

        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "test.jpg");
        try {
            f.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(f);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(path, "image/*");
        startActivity(intent);
```

**Note that *imagename* is the name of the image in your drawable folder**

**And don't forget to add *permission* for accessing SD card in *manifest* file**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I want to support phones which doesn't have SD card. Is it possible to use this solution with phone's local storage?

Comment: Yes..It is possible to store image in phones's internal memory...You can refer this..  http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that. This drawable is private for your application and other apps can't use it. You should create your own `ImageViewer` or copy these drawables to SD card and set that `Uri` when starting the `Intent`.

Comment: I can switch the folder from drawable to assets, is it possible with this folder ?

Answer (score 0):

you can access your image by this code :

```
R.drawable.image
```

for example you can use this code in your "onCreate" method:

```
ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
img.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.image);
```

Comment: I don't want to open image file with my imageviewer. I want to open it with Gallery/QuickPic/Instagram etc.