# Open image from res/drawable-hdpi in gallery when clicking a button

Tags: android, image, button

i have been goin through various posts to find a way to open a image from my res folder,
i have a button named share,i used the following code to do the same

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri uri=Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/a.jpg");
```

tried fetching from aseets but image not loaded.

```
 Uri imgUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"     +"drawable/a");
```

the app force closes when i use this uri.
`intent.setDataAndType(Uri.`parse("android.resource://com.example.hny_wallpaperset/" + R.drawable.a), "image/*");
app force closes

```
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
    startActivity(intent);
```

a is my image name,i also tried using my package name com.example.HNY_wallpaperset instead of getpackagename(),still same error.

any advice?

---

> Found the answer here --
>   [How to open an image in drawable folder using android imageview applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474061/how-to-open-an-image-in-drawable-folder-using-android-imageview-applications/19475520#19475520)

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is quick sample of one gallery activity if that is what you need anyway.

```
   public class ImageGalleryExample extends Activity implements
            AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            mSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.switcher);
            mSwitcher.setFactory(this);
            mSwitcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                    android.R.anim.fade_in));
            mSwitcher.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                    android.R.anim.fade_out));

            Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
            g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
            g.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        }

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            mSwitcher.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }

        public View makeView() {
            ImageView i = new ImageView(this);
            i.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000);
            i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            i.setLayoutParams(new ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            return i;
        }

        private ImageSwitcher mSwitcher;

        public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
            public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
                mContext = c;
            }

            public int getCount() {
                return mThumbIds.length;
            }

            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

                i.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
                i.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                i.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.picture_frame);
                return i;
            }

            private Context mContext;

        }

        private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
                R.drawable.sample_thumb_0, R.drawable.sample_thumb_1,
                R.drawable.sample_thumb_2, R.drawable.sample_thumb_3};

        private Integer[] mImageIds = {
                R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1, R.drawable.sample_2,
                R.drawable.sample_3};

    }
```

but if you just want to set src to image view then use simple:

```
myImgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sample_1);
```

btw, android itslef is choosing betwen `drawable-?dpi` folders

Comment: thnx for the help,i already have the image loaded on the imageview,when i click my share button the same image should open in gallery view,why im doing so is because i would like to use the controls like share in gallery view on my image

Comment: best way is probably to made another class with share utils, adapter for shares etc. plus you need FacebookEventObserver and TwitterEventObserver, you may find it on https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Simple-Social-Sharing

Comment: k,thnx for the info.i found smtin else tht does the purpose.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474061/how-to-open-an-image-in-drawable-folder-using-android-imageview-applications/19475520#19475520